# compute very special limit in real number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let the function $f:$ $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\inf\{|x-me|:m\in\Bbb{Z}\}$ and consider sequence $\{f(n)\}$ then which of the following options is true? 
a) $\{f(n)\}$ is convergence 
b)the set of  subsequence limits of $\{f(n)\}$ is [0,$\frac{e}{2}$] 
c) $\{f(n)\}$ has not subsequence convergence 
d) the set of  subsequence limits of $\{f(n)\}$ is utmost countable

Comment: I think that the sequence is fix zero and it is not true.

Comment: By the sequence {f(n)}, you are only considering $f$ at natural numbers? If this is the case, try writing out the first few terms. This should give you some intuition for a).

Answer (score 0):

I claim that the answer is (b). That is, for any $x \in [0, \frac{e}{2}]$, there exists a subsequence $f(n_k) \to x$. Let's prove this.

First notice that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a unique $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $|n-me| \in [0,\frac{e}{2}]$, i.e, such that $n \in [(m-\frac{1}{2})e, (m+\frac{1}{2})e]$. Therefore, if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, and if $|n-me| \in [0,\frac{e}{2}]$, then $|n-me|=f(n)$.

Choose any $x \in [0, \frac{e}{2})$ and let $\epsilon \in (0,\frac{e}{2}-x]$.

Let $X = \mathbb{R}/e \mathbb{Z}$, and consider the map $\phi: X \to X$ defined by $a \pmod e \mapsto (1+a) \pmod e$. Since $e$ is irrational, the ergodic theorem on the circle tells us that the orbit of $0$ under $\phi$ is dense in $X$, so we can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $|n-me-x|<\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon\leq \frac{e}{2}-x$, this implies that $|n-me| \in [0,\frac{e}{2}]$, so that $|n-me|=f(n)$, by our first comment. Thus $|f(n)-x|=\big||n-me|-x\big|<\epsilon$.

We showed that for any $x\in[0,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ and any $\epsilon \in (0,\frac{e}{2}-x]$, there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(n)-x|<\epsilon$. This implies the result in $(b)$.